# precompiled version that supports HORN?

Tags: z3

I see from previous discussions that the stable version does not support (set-logic HORN). Is there a precompiled version for downloading that does support it ?

Answer (score 1):

The "unstable" branch of Z3 has nightly builds and it includes HORN support.
Go to z3.codeplex.com and select downloads, then select "Planned" in the dialog box for executables.

There are several engines for HORN problems. In particular you can try also to enable the Duality engine using the option "fixedpoint.engine=duality".